# making two scroll list next to each other with a add and remove function with python

Tags: python, list, dictionary, tkinter

[I want to create two list like this one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fuJG1.png)

Hi I'm trying to make two lists next to each other like this one being a list of "things" and the other one a custom list of only the thing you want from the list of "thing" I'm using tkinter on python but would also use anything else that makes it easier at the moment I have a Dict of "thing" that I would rather use but if I cant ill use the list. thank you

ps: this is my first post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should give you an idea of how to go about implementing such widgets.

```
from tkinter import *

root =Tk()

lb = Listbox(root)
lb.grid(row=0, column=0, rowspan=6, columnspan=3)

sb1 = Scrollbar(root)
sb1.grid(row=0, column=3, rowspan=6)

sb1.configure(command=lb.yview) 
lb.configure(yscrollcommand=sb1.set)

button1 = Button(root, text="<", width=10).grid(row=0, column=4)
button2 = Button(root, text=">", width=10).grid(row=1, column=4)
button3 = Button(root, text=">>>", width=10).grid(row=2, column=4)
button4 = Button(root, text="<<<", width=10).grid(row=3, column=4)

listbox2 = Listbox(root).grid(row=0, column=5, rowspan=6, columnspan=8)



root.mainloop()
```

Consult the tkinter documentation http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/ for further understanding and next time when posting here, submit the code you have worked on to be able to get an assistance

Comment: Thank you for your help I will do that next time.